# MySQL: how to update a table based on changes to another table with trigger or stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, trigger, phpmyadmin

Because of the limitation of a wordpress plugin I am using I cannot update tables from the website when they are created from `JOIN` statement. So I created a bigger table with data of all tables. But I want that when a website user edits a field in this table then the update should be reflected to the "joined" tables.

For example I have these tables (in reality the tables have ~20 fields and the big one has ~50 fields):

Students:

```
+----+------+-----+
| id | name | age |
+----+------+-----+
|  1 | John |  34 |
|  2 | Mary |  21 |
+----+------+-----+
```

Courses:

```
+----+--------+----------+
| id | course | semester |
+----+--------+----------+
|  1 | math   | 1st      |
|  2 | geo    | 2n       |
+----+--------+----------+
```

Registrations:

```
+----+------------+------+-----+-----------+--------+----------+
| id | student_id | name | age | course_id | course | semester |
+----+------------+------+-----+-----------+--------+----------+
|  1 |          1 | John |  34 |         1 | math   | 1st      |
|  2 |          2 | Mary |  21 |         2 | geo    | 2n       |
+----+------------+------+-----+-----------+--------+----------+
```

So when user for example a user edits the name of a student then the edit has to be made both to the `Registrations` table and to the `Students`. But it has to be done via a `trigger` or a `stored procedure` in `phpmyadmin` because I dont want to change the functionality of the wordpress plugin. How I can create this kind of trigger or stored procedure in `Students` or `Courses`?

Comment: For such large tables you should use `views` not separate tables. `view` support all `CRUD` operations to their respective tables. `view` would exactly behave like a table, you don't need to change any code, just create the view with same name of your large table and remove the table. You should be good. To test whether it will work for you or not, do it in local or beta environment first.

Comment: I tried with a view but I couldn't update it. Probably is plugins limitation... https://wpdatatables.com/documentation/front-end-editing/creating-editable-tables/ MySQL Views cannot be edited properly – only one of the underlying tables can be edited if you pass the proper ID.